# Difference between `git commit` and `git merge --continue` after resolving all index/working-tree conflicts in a merge?

Tags: git

Is there any functional difference between `git commit` and `git merge --continue` after resolving all index/working-tree conflicts in a merge?

The manual somewhat obscurely says:

> Resolve the conflicts. Git will mark the conflicts in the working tree. Edit the files into shape and git add them to the index. Use `git commit` or `git merge --continue` to seal the deal. The latter command checks whether there is a (interrupted) merge in progress before calling git commit.

I don't' understand what the last sentence means. Is there any real difference between `git commit` and `git merge --continue` after resolving all conflicts in the working tree and index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git merge --continue` command simply *runs* `git commit`, after first verifying that there is a merge to finish.

There's a bug-ette in this in that `git commit` takes options that would be useful with `git merge --continue`, but `git merge` does not pass those options on.  So if you want to use `-m`, for instance, you must use the `git commit` form.