# Can I use `git commit` instead of `git cherry-pick --continue`?

Tags: git

Is `git cherry-pick --continue` a "bug-ette" [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70614309/difference-between-git-commit-and-git-merge-continue-after-resolving-all-i) `git merge --continue`, meaning I cannot pass in a custom commit message, especially when the cherry pick had merge conflicts, and I want to record in the cherry-pick-commit message a summary of how I solved them conflicts?

Basically, can I just use `git commit -m "blah"` to continue a cherry-pick, like I can do to finish-up a merge? Or do I need some more/other follow-up during a cherry-pick, if just issue a git commit instead of `git cherry-pick --continue`?

Ah, never mind, `git cherry-pick --continue` *does* pop up the editor for a commit message. No "bug-ette" in this case. Still, it might be an interesting question if `git commit` is sufficient to continue a cherry pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use `git cherry-pick --continue`.

Say you cherry-pick a few commits and it has conflicts for the first one. After `git commit`, the cherry-pick procedure pauses. If you don't use `git status`, or you haven't configured to show branch/status in PS1 (as it does on Windows git-bash), or you just forget that there are more commits, you would probably think that the cherry-pick is finished. And you still need to run `git cherry-pick --continue` to resume the procedure.

If you use `git cherry-pick --continue`, it starts to apply the next commit until all are done.

Comment: Note, though, that either one works fine for a single-commit cherry-pick. It's just those pesky multi-commit sequencer operations that demand the `--continue`. :-) I wonder if `git commit` should check for, and remind users of, any ongoing sequencer operations after the commit finishes.